# Customizing Headline Results in Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

Template: http://www.nathanieljohnston.com/2009/08/latex-poster-template/

I'm trying to add an "advisor" element to my headline by copying the format used in my .sty file.

Notice that I added another column to my headline which contains the "logo" element. This one works fine, and when I it from main.tex and .sty I get the same errors.

---

When I add the advisor element to my main.tex file I get the error:

```
Undefined control sequence. l.88 \advisor {Faculty Advisor} % Advisor
```

When I remove the \advisor tag from main.tex, but leave the element in my sty file:

```
Undefined control sequence. \beamer@@tmpl@headline ...}\large {\insertadvisor }} \usebeamercolor {instit... l.94
```

---

beamerthemeconfposter.sty slice:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{12em}
    \usebeamercolor{logo in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertlogo}}
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{advisor in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertadvisor}}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip0.5cm
   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}
```

---

Main.tex:

```
\logo{\tikzoverlay[text width=15em] at (1cm,2cm) {\includegraphics[width=15em]{logo.png}};}


\title{My title} % Poster title

\author{My Name} % Author(s)

\advisor{Faculty Advisor} % Advisor     <-------- ERROR


\institute{My Institute} % Institution(s)

\begin{document}         %              <------- ERROR
```

---

Can anyone help me fix my headline definitions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\advisor` is no macro which is available as default. As a workaround, you could define `\insertadvisor` yourself.

Please note that font commands such as `\Huge` or `\large` are switches and do not take arguments.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter}
\usepackage{exscale}

\title{This Was Made in \LaTeX}
\author{Your Name}
\institute{Department and University Name}
\newcommand{\insertadvisor}{Faculty Advisor}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
 \leavevmode
  \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{12em}
    \usebeamercolor{logo in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertlogo}}
   \end{column}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge \textbf{\inserttitle}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large \insertauthor\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\large \insertadvisor}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large \insertinstitute\\[1ex]}
    \vskip0.5cm
   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
  \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```